# On the efficiency of tries and radix sort

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, trie, radix-sort

Radix sort's time complexity is O(kn) where n is the number of keys to be sorted and k is the key length. Similarly, the time complexity for the insert, delete, and lookup operations in a trie is O(k). However, assuming all elements are distinct, isn't k>=log(n)? If so, that would mean Radix sort's asymptotic time complexity is O(nlogn), equal to that of quicksort, and trie operations have a time complexity of O(logn), equal to that of a balanced binary search tree. Of course, the constant factors may differ significantly, but the asymptotic time complexities won't. Is this true, and if so, do radix sort and tries have other advantages over other algorithms and data structures?

**Edit:**

Quicksort and its competitors perform O(nlogn) *comparisons*; in the worst case each comparison will take O(k) time (keys differ only at last digit checked). Therefore, those algorithms take O(knlogn) time. By that same logic, balanced binary search tree operations take O(klogn) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O notation is not used that way, even if k>=log n for radix sorting, O(kn) means that your processing time will double if n doubles and so on, this is how you should use big-o notation.

One advantage of radix sort is that it's worst case is O(kn) (quicksort's O(n^2)) so radix sort is somehow more resistant to malicious input than quicksort. It can also be really fast in term of real perfomance, if you use bitwise operations, a power of 2 as a base and in-place msd-radix sort with insertion sort for smaller arrays.

The same argument is valid for tries, they are resistant to malicious input in the sense that insertion/search is O(k) in the worst case. Hashtables perform insertion/search in O(1) but with O(k) hashing and in the worst case O(N) insertion/search. Also, tries can store strings more efficiently.

Check [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150ICS/handouts/eddie-presentation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic time complexity of Radix sort is O(NlogN) which is also the time complexity of Qucik sort. The advantage of Radix sort is that it's best, average and worst case performance is same where as the worst case performance of Quick sort is O(N^2). But it takes twice the sapce as required by Quick sort. So, if space complexity is not a problem then Radix sort is a better option.